# Facebook "Send Dialog" - how to track referrals

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use `Send Dialog` of facebook on my site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog)

I need to know if there is a way to `track Referrals` with this dialog? just as there is a `ref` param with `Send Button` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button).

I tried adding `ref` in the `FB.ui` as a param, but doesnt work..

Comment: I assume you are sharing a url? If so add something unique to that url so you know how generated the url

Comment: yea true, but I want not to do it and instead keep my url professional and simple to remember...

Comment: Then there is no way

Comment: :(.. so they added this in send Button, but not in send Dialog?!!